# Antlr parser operator priority

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4

Consider the following grammar. I have issues with the operator priority, for instance: `res=2*a+b` has a similar parse tree as `res=2*(a+b)`. I know where the problem is, but no "beautiful" solution without mutual left recursion comes to my mind. Can you please help me out a little? The grammar is used with a custom visitor.

```
grammar Math;

expression: expression add=('+'|'-') expression # expressionAddExpression
            | expression mult='*' expression    # expressionMultExpression
            |'(' expression ')'  # bracketExpression
            | number                            # numberExpression
            ;
    number: INT                                                                 #int
            | '(' number ')'                                                    #bracketNumber
            | VARIABLE                                                          #var

            ;
    VARIABLE: [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*;



INT: [0-9]+;
```

Answer (score 22):

From [The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference](https://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference), 5.4 Dealing with Precedence, Left Recursion, and Associativity :

```
expr : expr '*' expr // match subexpressions joined with '*' operator
     | expr '+' expr // match subexpressions joined with '+' operator
     | INT // matches simple integer atom
     ;
```

> The problem is that this rule is ambiguous for some input phrases. ...
>
> This is a question of operator precedence, and conventional grammars
>   simply have no way to specify precedence. Most grammar tools, such as
>   Bison, use extra notation to specify the operator precedence.
>
> Instead, ANTLR resolves ambiguities in favor of the alternative given
>   first, implicitly allowing us to specify operator precedence.

So simply put multiplication before addition.

File `Question.g4` :

```
grammar Question;

question
@init {System.out.println("Question last update 1213");}
    :   line+ EOF
    ;

line
    :   expression NL
        {System.out.println("Expression found : " + $expression.text); }
    ;

expression
    :   expression mult='*' expression          # expressionMultExpression
    |   expression add=( '+' | '-' ) expression # expressionAddExpression
    |   VARIABLE '=' expression                 # expressionAssign
    |   '(' expression ')'                      # parenthesisedExpression
    |   atom                                    # atomExpression
    ;

atom
    :   INT                                     #int
    |   VARIABLE                                #var
    ;

VARIABLE : LETTER ( LETTER | DIGIT )*;
INT      : DIGIT+;

NL      : [\r\n] ;
WS      : [ \t] -> channel(HIDDEN) ; // -> skip ;

fragment LETTER : [a-zA-Z] ;
fragment DIGIT  : [0-9] ;
```

File `input.txt` :

```
res = 2 * a + b
res = 2 * ( a + b )
```

Execution :

```
$ grun Question question -tokens -diagnostics input.txt 
[@0,0:2='res',<VARIABLE>,1:0]
[@1,3:3=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:3]
[@2,4:4='=',<'='>,1:4]
[@3,5:5=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:5]
[@4,6:6='2',<INT>,1:6]
[@5,7:7=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:7]
[@6,8:8='*',<'*'>,1:8]
[@7,9:9=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:9]
[@8,10:10='a',<VARIABLE>,1:10]
...
[@32,36:35='<EOF>',<EOF>,3:0]
Question last update 1213
Expression found : res = 2 * a + b
Expression found : res = 2 * ( a + b )
```

and

```
$ grun Question question -gui input.txt
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I was familiar with this section of the antlr reference but it did not work as expected. Due to a broken build script, changing the order of the rules did not make any difference, now its working flawlessly

Comment: I see you placed fragments at the end. Since they're not tokens, I'm assuming it doesn't matter where they appear in the lexer; is that correct?

Comment: @raffian Fragments are helper rules for the lexer. If you have several rules using `[0-9]`, it's easier, and more readable, to say `DIGIT`. It's convenient to group fragments at the end of the grammar, they are easier to find, like footnotes at the bottom of a page. However you can write them anywhere in the grammar.